# SQL How to query customers who have made a purchase at least once a year since they first start purchasing?

Tags: sql

[image]

I want to query customers who have made at least 10 purchases a year since they started shopping with us.
Customer 1 would not qualify because he made >10 purchases in 2018 and 2020 but 0 in 2019.
Customer 2 would qualify.
Customer 3 would not qualify because he made less than 10 purchases in 2018 even though he did make consecutive purchase. The time window depends on when the customer first shopped with us. What SQL query should I use to filter out customer 2 from the others?

Comment: Version of MySQL **(critical)**?

Comment: Mysql and ms sql server are two different database products with different implementations of sql. Removed the conflicting product tags. Pls add the one back that you are actually using!

Comment: Hi - in future could you please provide your table structures as DDL and data as DML - better, provide a fiddle like [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a2b5ec873f8cef7e396775137922bf65).. but put that data and SQL here also! See my comment on the answer below!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` and `having` as follows:

```
Select customerid
  From t
Group by customerid
Having max(year) - min(year) + 1 = count(distinct year) 
   and min(purchase) > 10
```

Comment: You should have (max(p_year) - min(p_year)) **+ 1** = count... see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a2b5ec873f8cef7e396775137922bf65).it's also not a good idea to have field- (or table-) names that are also SQL keywods (e.g. `year`).

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want every year *up to the current year*.  Or, at least, up to the maximum year in the data.

```
select t.customerid
from (select t.*, max(year) over () as max_year
      from t
     ) t
group by customerid, max_year
having max_year - min(year) + 1 = count(distinct year) and
       min(purchase) >= 10;
```

This would disallow a customer who made more than 10 purchases in 2017 and 2018 but has no data in 2019 or 2020.

Comment: Your answer doesn't quite work - see [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=63b90ebacb2332bd61aae65a06dfaea4) - you need a second `HAVING` clause `AND MIN(t.purchase) >= 10;` - the `WHERE` doesn't work! Still, I like your idea about counting back from the current year (or at least the most recent for which data would be available/applicable) - +1!

Comment: @Vérace . . . This checks the purchase in the `where` clause not the `having` clause.  Why doesn't the `where` work?  It certainly should.  If any rows are missing from the years, then they are filtered out.

Comment: Did you even look at my fiddle above? Below see both `WHERE t.purchase >= 10` (result 2 & 3 - your code only) and in a (your code modified by me) different snippet, `HAVING max_year... AND MIN(t.p_cnt) >= 10` (result 2 - which is what is required by the OP). Now, I've added 4, with purchases in 2010-2012 incl. and then from 2018-2020 inc. My first (obviously incorrect) take on your solution was that your SQL would include 4, since they've been good clients for a while - i.e. they could have been clients 2014-20 incl. and still won't appear. I think there's a gaps-and-islands problem there?

Comment: [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d51baf92a789b494bf24badd96a9478e) for my comment above. What I mean by the above is that if there is at least 2 (or 3, 4...) years of continuous purchases up to and including 2020 (and some earlier - but **with** a gap), then that customer should also appear?

Comment: @Vérace . . . Very good catch.  You are correct.  I adjusted the answer.

Comment: But it still doesn't do what I want - if a customer has been a regular (>= 10/annum) over the last, say, 5 years (arbitrary - up to OP at the end of the day), then they might **also** merit being included? I mean a gap of 1 year in 2011 and then many purchases (>= 10 from 2012 - 2020) since might also be a "good" client? I'd be interested in tackling that one - any ideas?

Comment: @Vérace . . .That is a different question and should be asked as a *new* question.  The question you asked here has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

in mysql you could try:

```
SELECT *  FROM (
    SELECT t.CustomerID, COUNT(*) AS yearsPurchasing, t2.firstYear
    FROM customers t
    JOIN (
        SELECT CustomerID, MIN(YEAR) AS firstYear
        FROM customers 
        GROUP BY CustomerID
    ) t2 ON t2.CustomerID = t.CustomerID
    WHERE t.Purchase >= 10
    GROUP BY t.CustomerID
) r  WHERE  2020 + 1 = firstYear + yearsPurchasing
```

2020 is the year they should have purchased to qualify, if you want the actual year, you could use YEAR(NOW()) instead 2020, if you want until the last year change 2020 + 1 by YEAR(NOW()), tell me if it works.