# List (loyal) customers who've made purchases in every year

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to list customer_id's that have made purchases from every distinctly available year from a column.

The column is in sales.orders called 'order_date'

This is what I've done so far (didn't work):

```
--List customers who've made purchases in every year
SELECT customer_id
FROM sales.orders
WHERE year(order_date) = ALL (
    select distinct YEAR(order_date)
    from sales.orders
)
```

I wanted something that shows the customer_id only if they've made purchases at least once a year since opening.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL How to query customers who have made a purchase at least once a year since they first start purchasing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65747105/sql-how-to-query-customers-who-have-made-a-purchase-at-least-once-a-year-since-t)

Comment: @Larnu No, because I don't have a column that tells me how many times a customer has made an order. Even if I did, all orders might be made in the same year. I want my results to only show customers who've made purchases in ever single year since opening of the store.

Comment: *"No, because I don't have a column that tells me how many times a customer has made an order"* But you can work that out, with `COUNT`. Though, for the solutions, you don't actually need that column anyway, so your point is somewhat moot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `COUNT`, @Lanru suggestion was not Wrong.

Here what you can do

Assuming that your table look like below :

```
CREATE TABLE sales.orders 
( 
    customer_id NVARCHAR(4000), 
    order_date date
); 

INSERT INTO sales.orders (customer_id, order_date) VALUES ('C1001', '10-10-2020'); 
INSERT INTO sales.orders (customer_id, order_date) VALUES ('C1002', '10-10-2020'); 
INSERT INTO sales.orders (customer_id, order_date) VALUES ('C1003', '10-10-2020'); 
INSERT INTO sales.orders (customer_id, order_date) VALUES ('C1002', '10-10-2022'); 
INSERT INTO sales.orders (customer_id, order_date) VALUES ('C1001', '10-10-2021'); 
INSERT INTO sales.orders (customer_id, order_date) VALUES ('C1001', '10-10-2021'); 
INSERT INTO sales.orders (customer_id, order_date) VALUES ('C1001', '10-10-2022'); 
INSERT INTO sales.orders (customer_id, order_date) VALUES ('C1003', '10-10-2020'); 
INSERT INTO sales.orders (customer_id, order_date) VALUES ('C1003', '10-10-2020'); 
INSERT INTO sales.orders (customer_id, order_date) VALUES ('C1003', '10-10-2021'); 
INSERT INTO sales.orders (customer_id, order_date) VALUES ('C1003', '10-10-2022'); 
INSERT INTO sales.orders (customer_id, order_date) VALUES ('C1003', '10-10-2022');
```

This is the solutions you're asking for :

```
    SELECT me.customer_id FROM (
SELECT  DISTINCT customer_id, 
        COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(order_date)) AS 'count_year'
FROM sales.orders
GROUP BY customer_id ) AS me
WHERE me.count_year = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT YEAR(order_date) ) FROM sales.orders)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM sales.customers
WHERE customer_id IN (
        SELECT t.customer_id
        FROM (
            SELECT o.customer_id,
                count(DISTINCT (year(order_date))) AS cnt
            FROM sales.orders AS o
            GROUP BY customer_id
            ) t
        WHERE t.cnt = (
                SELECT count(DISTINCT (year(order_date)))
                FROM sales.orders
                )
        )
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Reposting the same answer that i provided you and acceting your own answer is kinda unethical.